# Django: Check if user input does not exist in db and throw ValidationError

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have an IntegerField in my form where a user can input an `id`. Before the form is submitted I want to check if that `id` actually exists and if it doesn't I want to throw the user a Validation Error if it doesn't. I've tried the following. Is there an easier way to do this?

**forms.py**

```
class IncidentSearchForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.IntegerField(label="ID",required=False)

    def search(self):
        id = self.cleaned_data.get('id')
        try:
            incident_id = Incident.object.filter(pk=id).exists()
        except Incident.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This does not exist.')

    query = Incident.objects.all()

    if id is not None:
        query = query.filter(id=self.cleaned_data.get('id'))

    return(query)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since you need a custom validator(as you mentioned in comments), you can create a `validate_id_exists` validator  for your `id` field.**

`validate_id_exists` validator checks if an `Incident` object exists with the given `id`. If it does not exists, it raises a `ValidationError`.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_id_exists(value):
    incident = Incident.objects.filter(id=value)
    if not incident: # check if any object exists
        raise ValidationError('This does not exist.')
```

Then you can specify this validator in your form as `validators` argument to `id` field.

```
class IncidentSearchForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.IntegerField(label="ID", required=False, validators=[validate_id_exists]) # specify your 'id' validator here
```

Comment: Thanks! This was more along the lines of what I was looking for through @BogdiG definitely helped me out with some conceptual hiccups.

Comment: for any `id` I enter it throws me `Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
type object 'Incident' has no attribute 'object'
Exception Location: /home/informatics/dilts/DJANGO/CMIRS_D/incidents/forms.py in validate_id_exists, line 19` I'm at a loss. I'm reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/ and it seems to be correct.

Comment: got it!  `objects` not `object`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo from my end! changed `object` to `objects`. Updated the ans! Great that you fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this inside the form:

```
def clean_id(self):
    """
    Cleaning id field
    """
    id = self.cleaned_data.get('id', None)
    if id:
        try:
            incident = Incident.objects.get(pk=id)
        except Incident.DoesNotExist():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This does not exist.')
    return id
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/):

> The clean_() method is called on a form subclass – where
>    is replaced with the name of the form field attribute.
>   This method does any cleaning that is specific to that particular
>   attribute, unrelated to the type of field that it is. This method is
>   not passed any parameters. You will need to look up the value of the
>   field in self.cleaned_data and remember that it will be a Python
>   object at this point, not the original string submitted in the form
>   (it will be in cleaned_data because the general field clean() method,
>   above, has already cleaned the data once).

Comment: Thanks! It shows me now if the id I put in does not exists, but how do I give it a validator?

Comment: you mean you want to also throw validation error if there is no id?

Comment: yes. for the user to see. something like `id = forms.IntegerField(
  label="ID",
  required=False,
  validators=["This does not exist."])`

Comment: I'm not quite following you. I use the `is_valid()` in view before the data gets to this point. It should already be cleaned with that call. I'm not understanding the relationship between what you submitted and throwing a validation error. Unless you mean clean() checks if the data is actually in the db or not.

Comment: when you call is_valid() on the form, a few steps are performed by the form before you get the result (see more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/) read the info at the beginning; You can individually clean a field through the above example; if the validation fails, is_valid() will return false; What you would do afterwards is send the form instance that failed back to the user (form instance will contain the errors!) and show the errors in the template https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

Comment: I read through all of the documentation multiple times. I need to know how to show the error in the template. I will keep trying. Do I always have to send the form instance back? I've used validators on other fields with RegexValidator where I didn't need to send the form instance back.

Comment: depends on how you render the form. if you use {{ form.as_p }}, that's taken care for you; if you loop through the form fields manually, you can do {% for field in form %} {{ field.errors }}  {% endfor %} ; Bare in mind you need to send back the form instance that failed validation! More about rendering form errors here :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: "We call the form’s is_valid() method; if it’s not True, we go back to the template with the form. This time the form is no longer empty (unbound) so the HTML form will be populated with the data previously submitted, where it can be edited and corrected as required" ; source -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: You were right. I was sending back an instance as `{% if form.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}` and I didn't even remember. Thanks for being patient with me.